# Enabling jdwp on a jdk 14 app results in Address family not supported by protocol error

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jdwp

For a JDK 14 application, running on linux, adding the following JVM parameter

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`

results in the following error

```
Starting Main...
ERROR: transport error 202: socket creation failed: Address family not supported by protocol
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [open/src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:734]
```

Changing the address from `*:5005` to `localhost:5005` seems to work but then it's only bound to localhost. I know for a fact that `*:5005` worked on JDK 12 and I can't find any changes regarding this, In fact JPDA spec still mentions the `*` option for jse 14 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/jpda/conninv.html.  Anyone got any ideas what I can look into? Is it a bug or a feature for which I can't seem to find documentation for.

Comment: By default, jdwp agent tries to bind to `[::]`. Apparently, IPv6 does not work on your system. Try `0.0.0.0:5005` or add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` JVM option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @apangin suggested in the comment. The solution is to specify the address as `0.0.0.0:5005` or to set the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` JVM parameter.